# how to get real IE work Area with C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get the working area of IE browser
What i have now is this code:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle resolution = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
```

what I'm getting with this code is this:

```
-       resolution  {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1366 Height = 728} System.Drawing.Rectangle
        Bottom  728 int
        Height  728 int
        IsEmpty false   bool
        Left    0   int
+       Location    {X = 0 Y = 0}   System.Drawing.Point
        Right   1366    int
+       Size    {Width = 1366 Height = 728} System.Drawing.Size
        Top 0   int
        Width   1366    int
        X   0   int
        Y   0   int
```

It's all good but I get height as 728 and that include the toolbar and the menu, I need the real working area without the toolbar and the menu.

Image as example:
[image: Example for problem]

I need the size of the work area.

for me it's **585 px.**
But it's need to be Dynamic for other resolutions and

Comment: Inner width? With JS that is http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Comment: well, that a nice javaScript code but i need it in C#,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that i can use the **IE Object**

and then all i need is to request this

```
this.HTMLDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight;
```